Auto login with a url
I have this react-native project using expo. I have a normal login endpoint, and I wanted to make another endpoint with the hardcoded credentials:
app.get("/login/:email/:password", async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    try {
        const result = await loginUser(email, password);
        res.json(result);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.toString() });
    }
});

What I'm trying to achieve here is to store the URL with the credentials inside an NFC card when a worker opens this from his browser and then he opens the app in expo he automatically gets redirected to the Home page. For example, I have this link http://localhost:3000/login/admin@admin/admin I save this into the NFC card and when the user scans the card, the website is opened and makes a GET to the login. When the user opens the app in expo he automatically gets redirected to the Home. One problem might be that I'm doing a get and not a post, but I don't know how to store a post request into an NFC. Another problem is that the storage of the browser is not connected to expo. How can I do this? By the way here I'll provide my code for everything:
async function loginUser(username, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(
            "SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE email = ?",
            [username],
            function (error, results, fields) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    if (results.length > 0) {
                        bcrypt.compare(
                            password,
                            results[0].password,
                            function (err, result) {
                                if (result) {
                                    const isAdmin =
                                        username === "admin@admin.com";
                                    console.log("loginUser", results[0].nome);
                                    resolve({
                                        loggedIn: true,
                                        name: results[0].nome,
                                        isAdmin,
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    resolve({ loggedIn: false });
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    } else {
                        resolve({ loggedIn: false });
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    });
}

And this is the LoginPage.tsx:
useEffect(() => {
        const checkUserLoggedIn = async () => {
            const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("loggedIn");
            const isAdmin = await AsyncStorage.getItem("isAdmin");
            if (user === "true") {
                if (isAdmin === "true") {
                    navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace("Dipendenti"));
                } else {
                    navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace("Home"));
                }
            }
        };
        checkUserLoggedIn();
    }, []);

    const handleLogin = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://${ip}:3000/login`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
            });

            const responseText = await response.text();
            console.log("Response text:", responseText);

            let data;
            try {
                data = JSON.parse(responseText);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error parsing response as JSON:", error);
            }

            if (data && data.loggedIn) {
                console.log("LoginPage", data.name);
                setCurrentProfile({ email, name: data.name });
                if (isRememberMeChecked) {
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem("loggedIn", "true");
                    setCurrentProfile({ email, name: data.name });
                }
                if (data.isAdmin) {
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem("isAdmin", "true");
                    navigation.dispatch(
                        StackActions.replace("Dipendenti", { email: email })
                    );
                } else {
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem("isAdmin", "false");
                    navigation.dispatch(
                        StackActions.replace("Home", { email: email })
                    );
                }
            } else {
                Alert.alert("Login fallito", "Credenziali errate");
            }
        } catch (error: any) {
            Alert.alert("Login error", error.toString());
        }
        setLoading(false);
    };

Thanks
